# In JBoss 6.2.3 GA domain mode, where do you find the deployed files?

Tags: java, jboss, web-deployment, jboss6.x

In JBoss 6.2.3 GA using domain managed mode, I have deployed a WAR file that has been deployed across two instances.
I would like to make sure that a specific file has been included properly wherever each instance has deployed the WAR.
So I'm looking for where to find the deployed files, or the setting(s) that details where the deployed files will be.
I'm definitely open to alternate ways of accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jboss EAP stores the deployed files in the following path.

```
${jboss_home}/domain/data/content
```

Inside the path, It will create a new folder for all the deployments with the SHA value.

**Eg:**

```
${jboss_home}/domain/data/content/0e/f97f01403357a4955f6b17cbf69850825af0a1/content
```

In the above, the following folder is the SHA value /0e/f97f01403357a4955f6b17cbf69850825af0a1

And after the SHA value there should always be your war file ( content ).

New SHA value will be generated for each deployment activity. Check domain.xml for the current SHA value for your deployed war.

**For Eg :**

```
    <deployment name="application.war" runtime-name="application.war">
        <content sha1="0ef97f01403357a4955f6b17cbf69850825af0a1"/>
    </deployment>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as the instructions helped resolve the issue. I was, however, interested in the documentation behind this solution, as I couldn't find it anywhere. Would you, @ArunRaj, or someone else be willing to provide a link to the pertinent sections?